# onLoadChildren never gets called in MediaBrowserServiceCompat

Tags: android, auto, android-auto

I have implemented `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` in my application.

```
@Override
public BrowserRoot onGetRoot(@NonNull String s, int i, @Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.e("testing","onGetRoot");
    return new BrowserRoot(MEDIA_ID_ROOT, null);
}
```

App is entering `onGetRoot` method when I open Android auto app in my phone, but the method `onLoadChildren` never gets called. So I am not able to load my music folders.

Comment: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/mediabrowserservicecompat-and-the-modern-media-playback-app-7959a5196d90

Comment: I've inspected sources and came up to a conclusion, that you are not performing [`connect()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/MediaBrowserCompat.html#connect()) on your `MediaBrowserCompat` instance. Can you verify you are performing `connect()`?

Comment: If this is still unresolved, can you add the implementation of onLoadChildren()?  Do you have a logs at the beginning of it, and that's how you've determined it isn't being called? It may be possible its being called, just that there are no children in the root node being sent from onGetRoot()

Comment: Same here. Connect() is called, onGetRoot() is called, but onLoadChildren never gets called

Answer (score 6):

You must call `setSessionToken(...)` in the overridden `onCreate()` method of the service.

Answer (score 1):

oh god. The MediaBrowser client shouldn't just call connect() on the mediaBrowser instance as mentioned in the Google example at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowser-client

But you have to actually call subscribe in order to trigger the callback to onLoadChildren()

That documentation is just so messy and one needs to do a whole lot of puzzling (hours to days) to figure out how to get a simple MediaBrowserService up and running. :(

Comment: Can you please explain this a little bit further? What do you mean one should call a subscribe, there is not even a subscribe method on either MediaControllerCompat and MediaBrowserCompat